# Can't get jupyter notebook to run when I put in python shell

Tags: python, shell, pip, jupyter-notebook, version

When I type `python --version` in python 3.9 shell, I get python not defined.
The same command does not work when run from saved file or from shell.
When I type `pip install jupyter` I get invalid syntax.

Am I doing something wrong?

I just installed python and am just beginning with it and not sure why I can't get these to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found issue. You cannot get "python --version" by typing it into the python shell, I typed it into the command prompt for windows and it worked fine. Maybe I will have the jupyter thing figured out by tommorow.